# setof in model data and script files for NEOS server

Tags: set, ampl, neos-server

In submitting my AMPL formulation to the NEOS server, why does the below codeline using the `setof' operator work fine in a model file but not in a data file?

```
set X := setof {indices in Y} subsetofindices
```

The NEOS server requires the code be separated into a .mod , .dat, and script file separately. I've seen references to use `let` `X :=  ...` in the script file. What is the difference between these files, and what to put where?

**Example**
Using AMPL's steelT.x files, this first block of 2 files works

```
# steelT.mod
set DUMMYPROD;
set PROD := setof {i in DUMMYPROD} i;     # products
# steelT.dat
data;
set DUMMYPROD := bands coils;
```

Whereas the following does not work:

```
# steelT.mod
set DUMMYPROD;
set PROD;     # products
# steelT.dat
data;
set DUMMYPROD := bands coils;
set PROD := setof {i in DUMMYPROD} i;
```

It returns the error

> expected ; ( : or symbol
>   context:  set PROD := setof  >>> { <<< i in DUMMYPROD} i;

**Broader question**
Generally, what belongs in the model file, data file and script file? (Also for `param` and other definitions) What is the order in which these are processed? I may be missing some basics as I read the AMPL guide where I did not find this (I never took an Optimization course).

**Bonus question about NEOS server**
"New" [Contraint programming logic in AMPL](http://ampl.com/resources/logic-and-constraint-programming-extensions/) includes conditional and logical operators for entire constraints. I don't think these are available in NEOS. Or are they (because they didn't work for me)? Is there a simple workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMPL data format doesn't support expressions, so you should either use `setof {i in DUMMYPROD} i` in the declaration (as in your first example) or in the AMPL script:

```
let PROD := setof {i in DUMMYPROD} i;
```

See also [Chapter 9. Specifying Data](http://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/12-data.pdf) of the AMPL book for more details on the AMPL data format.

As for the constraint programming (CP) features, I don't think there are any CP solvers on NEOS. You can try contacting [NEOS Support](http://neos-guide.org/content/contact-us) regarding this.